# node with express performs next() without running if statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have 2 if statements as middleware in my express app. The first one no problem, but before the second one it performs the next() function without running the second if statement.

```
  app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    const email: string = req.body.email;
    const phoneNum: string = req.body.phone;
    console.log(phoneNum);
    if (phoneNum) {
        if (!phone(phoneNum).isValid) {
            res.json({
                message: "invalid phone format. Expecting format like: 8001234567",
            });
        } else {
            req.body.phone = phone(phoneNum).phoneNumber;
        }
    }
    if (email) {
        if (!EmailValidator.validate(email)) {
            res.json({
                message: "invalid email format. Expecting format like: name@domain.com",
            });
        }
    }
    next();
});
```

UPDATE: I tried return statements but the client doesn't receive a response. Updated code:

```
    app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    const email: string = req.body.email;
    const phoneNum: string = req.body.phone;
    console.log(phoneNum);
    if (phoneNum) {
        if (!phone(phoneNum).isValid) {
            res.json({
                message: "invalid phone format. Expecting format like: 8001234567",
            });
        } else {
            req.body.phone = phone(phoneNum).phoneNumber;
            return;
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
    if (email) {
        if (!EmailValidator.validate(email)) {
            res.json({
                message: "invalid email format. Expecting format like: name@domain.com",
            });
        } else {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: Right now `next` will be called no matter what. Do you want to `return` inside your `if` statements to make sure the next middleware isn't run?

Comment: @Nick I think you get where I'm going. I read your profile and wanted to thank you for your service. On the return statements, that gives a new problem. It does not give a response to the client. I updated the code in the question.

Comment: That's close to what i was suggesting! I added an answer to show exactly where I suspect you'll want to `return`. Basically, anywhere you're sending a response, I'm guessing that should be the end of the request.

Comment: I'm a beginner fyi, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to fully tell the context of this middleware, but my instinct is that you want to `return` whenever you're sending a response to the client:

```js
app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
  const email: string = req.body.email;
  const phoneNum: string = req.body.phone;
  console.log(phoneNum);
  if (phoneNum) {
    if (!phone(phoneNum).isValid) {
      res.json({
        message: "invalid phone format. Expecting format like: 8001234567",
      });
      return;
    } else {
      req.body.phone = phone(phoneNum).phoneNumber;
    }
  }
  if (email) {
    if (!EmailValidator.validate(email)) {
      res.json({
        message: "invalid email format. Expecting format like: name@domain.com",
      });
      return;
    }
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, @Nick. This helped. The middleware runs at every request and verifies if it's the proper format for emails and phone numbers. I will conclude that next() runs by default after sending a response unless I add return.